# Spotify Web API for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, spotify, libspotify

I am developing Windows Phone 8 application, in which I want to get recommended tracks of the user of Spotify. I would like to add these tracks of the user into favourites of my application. 
I need to login and get the track list and details which I can show in  my application. 
There is Spotify library available for Windows(Win32). Can this library be used for Windows Phone as well??
Please let me know if anyone know how to integrate spotify into Windows Phone.

Thanks,
Manmath

Comment: There are two questions. First is valid and answer is NO and it has already been answered by Spotify's staff. Second question is offtopic and too broad. Please also note that StackOverflow is not Spotify's support site.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 libspotify library cannot be used on Windows phone, and the REST-based Web API isn't powerful to do what you're asking. Unfortunately, there isn't a full-featured API available for Windows Phone.